# Enabling USB Debugging on locked (FRP) android phone

Tags: adb, samsung

I have a Samsung J5 Prime (SM-G570F/DS) that has been factory reset and now asking for Google account.

I've read this can be bypassed if ADB is enable. So I would like to know a way to do so.

As I have access on Recovery menu and Download Mode, should I flash something that can enable USB Debugging?

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by flashing an Eng ROM aka [Combination file](https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/security/combination-file-galaxy-mobile-t3404658) with Odin in download mode. But flashing just a modified SBOOT is necessary.